# Join mp3 exported from audacity with image using FFMPEG but youtube cannot process it

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube

Is there some cause to this incompatibility : how to fix this ?

I can play it locally.

I'm using an animated gif 1766 * 1080 FPS 4 I converted to mp4

```
ffmpeg.exe -i test.gif -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" "test.mp4"
```

then I join mp3 with mp4

```
ffmpeg.exe -i sound.mp3 -i test.mp4 -map 0:v? -map 1:a -c copy out.mp4
```

Comment: we can't tell  what kind of image you used, and what kind of `ffmpeg` command line you used. Please **edit** your question to include that information!

Comment: @MarcusMüller sorry so I updated

Comment: I think you should use `-map 1:v -map 0:a` (not sure what the question mark is for) if you have `-i sound.mp3` before `-i test.mp4`. (So you can reorder that instead as well.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all in one command:

```
ffmpeg -ignore_loop false -i video.gif -i audio.mp3 -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -c:a copy -shortest output.mkv
```

Because it is for YouTube you can ignore `-pix_fmt`, [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the audio, and put it into Matroska container. YouTube automatically re-encodes everything you give it.